# select child element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, liquid

I have a table structured like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  for loop here
    <tr>
      <td>Item X Attribute 1</td>
      <td>Item X Attribute 2</td>
      <td><button name="test" onclick="display_variants()">Hide my kids</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <tbody class="variants_info">
        <tr>
          <td>Item X Variant 1</td>
          <td>Item X Variant 2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </tr>
endfor loop
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So that structure repeats Y amount of times.

I'm trying to make a script that hides the `tbody.variants` of the row selected.

What I have so far is this:

```
<script>
  function display_variant(){
    if($('.variants_info').is(":visible")){
        $('.variants_info').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('.variants_info').show();
    }
  }
</script>
```

but this hides the variants from **ALL** the rows.

Is there a way to select the childs of the specific row? Also how can I start with the `tbody.variants` hidden? (Start as in when I visit the page).

Edit: At the moment is looking closely to this:
[image]

**Update:**
I've managed to change the structure to this:

```
<table>
  for loop
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>image for el 1</td>
        <td>attr for el 1</td>
        <td><button type='button' name='test'>Click Me</button></td>
      </tr>
      for loop
        <tr class='variants_info'>
          <td>variant1 for el 1</td>
          <td>variant2 for el 1</td>
        </tr>
      endfor
    </tbody>
  endfor
</table>
```

**Update 2:** The actual code is this one:

```
<table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered">
  <tbody>
  {% for product in collection.products %}
  {% if product.available %}

    <tr class="{% cycle 'pure-table-odd', '' %}">
      <td>
        <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'thumb' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}" />
      </td>
      <td>{{ product.title }}</td>
      <td style="text-align:right">
        <button type="button" name="click_me">Click Me</button>
      </td>
      </tr>
      {% for variant in product.variants %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{variant.title}}</td>
      <td>{{variant.price | money }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}       
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $("td button").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle();
  })
</script>
```

I still can't get the JS to work.. =/ Current one is only hiding the first variant( Instead of all the variants for the clicked button )

Comment: Use `$(this)`. Its like magic.

Comment: Hide your kids, hide your wifi

Comment: Here's an unrelated tip `$('.variants_info').toggle()`

Comment: I guess I probably just don't understand how StackOverflow works, but it seems anti-intuitive that there is an Open Bounty on a question with an accepted answer. Shouldn't the accepted answer automatically get the bounty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to mark the rows that contain the products with a class name, e.g. "product", like this:

```
<tr class="product {% cycle 'pure-table-odd', '' %}">
  <td>
    <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'thumb' }}" 
         alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}" />
  </td>
  <td>{{ product.title }}</td>
  <td style="text-align:right">
    <button type="button" name="click_me">Click Me</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

You would *not* add that class to the rows that have the variants.

Then in your JavaScript use the [`nextUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method to match all next variant rows (which do not have the "product" class) until, but excluding, the next *product* row, and apply the `toggle()` method to all these:

```
$("td button").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('.product').toggle();
});
```

#### Alternative structure 1

Instead of a single table, you could create nested tables, one for each product, containing the variants. It would look somewhat like this:

```
<table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered">
  <tbody>
  {% for product in collection.products %}
  {% if product.available %}

    <tr class="{% cycle 'pure-table-odd', '' %}">
      <td>
        <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'thumb' }}" 
             alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}" />
      </td>
      <td>{{ product.title }}</td>
      <td style="text-align:right">
        <button type="button" name="click_me">Click Me</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <table class="some other class specific for variants">
          <tbody> 
            {% for variant in product.variants %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{variant.title}}</td>
              <td>{{variant.price | money }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </tr>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This has advantages and disadvantages. The main disadvantage is that the columns of these sub-tables are not aligned with the columns in the main table. But it depends on what you want...

The JavaScript code would then have to be like you had it originally:

```
$("td button").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle();
});
```

#### Alternative structure 2

You could also wrap each "section" (consisting of one product row and the variant rows that belong to it) with a `tbody` tag. Although not commonly done, this is allowed as stated on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody):

> Note that unlike the `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, and `<caption>` elements however, multiple `<tbody>` elements are permitted (if consecutive), allowing the data-rows in long tables to be divided into different sections, each separately formatted as needed.

This is different from your original HTML, where you had `tbody` elements as children of `tr` elements, which is invalid HTML.

It would look like this:

```
<table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered">
  {% for product in collection.products %}
  {% if product.available %}

  <tbody>
    <tr class="{% cycle 'pure-table-odd', '' %}">
      <td>
        <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'thumb' }}" 
             alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}" />
      </td>
      <td>{{ product.title }}</td>
      <td style="text-align:right">
        <button type="button" name="click_me">Click Me</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{variant.title}}</td>
      <td>{{variant.price | money }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

You can then use the `nextAll()` method to hide the variant rows, because they are delimited by the `tbody` wrapper from the next product row:

```
$("td button").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').nextAll().toggle();
});
```

#### Initially hiding the variant rows

If you want the variants all to be hidden at first, then add the following attribute to those rows in the HTML code:

```
<tr style="display:hidden">
```

You would of course not do this for the product rows. Also, you might want to define a CSS class for this (e.g. `tr.hidden { display:hidden; }` instead of using `style`.

The jQuery `toggle()` method will override this `style` when showing, and restore it again when hiding.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you. Is that a proper table structure or you think it could be improved? Also.. Is there a way to make the variants toggled by default?

Comment: It seems OK. Alternatively you could nest the variant rows inside a sub-table. But that also has disadvantages. I will describe it in my answer in a minute.

Comment: Ok.. If you know something about the default toggle it would be lovely !

Comment: I added a paragraph on how to have the variant rows all hidden at first.

Answer (score 3):

Your `HTML` is not valid so you can change that and then use this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/678/)

```js
$("td button").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle();
})
```

Comment: Explanation for the OP: First, don't apply handlers in HTML. When you handle an event, `this` is a reference to the object that you registered the click on. If you search from there instead of a global search as you have, you can find the element within its context

Comment: I think the OP wanted `$(this).closest('tr').next().find('.variants_info').toggle();`

Comment: What part is not working, you have to change your HTML structure, because you can't have `tbody` inside `tbody`

Comment: I can't make 2 separate for loops since the variants are only accesible in that loop ( scope issues ).

Comment: @Onilol That doesn't make sense, you just have to get rid of the extra `<tbody><tr>`

Comment: This is only hidding the first variant.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean in demo it works for both tables.

Answer (score 1):

try this one :-

```
$("td button").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil("tbody").toggle();
});
```

the jsfiddle demo link is :- https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/776/